# Can I model one prevalence on another?

Tags: regression, logistic

I have 52,840 survey responses covering 2012-2015. I've produced 14 different small area estimates for survey variables like obesity, binge drinking, smoking, etc. These estimates were created using a generalized linear mixed model approach.

I'd like to see whether or not there are overlapping areas with high smoking predicted prevalence and high (insert variable) prevalence. I'm going to be using the 1st and 2nd highest quintiles to define an area of high smoking prevalence. However I'd like to determine which handful of other variables to model. I have an idea based on peer literature review but want to show why I chose these.

Can I model smoking prevalence based on the other prevalences via logistic regression? Is there too much error from the previous modeling iteration, even if I'm treating the small area prevalence as "true"? Is it better to model on the unweighted survey responses that initially went into the prevalence small area estimation?

Thanks